# Use list comprehension to create 2-numbers-tuple list with all possible pairs up to N

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to create a list of *2-numbers-tuple* - `(0,0) , (0,1) , ... (0,N-1) , (1,0) ... (N-1,N-1)` using list comprehension.

I used something like this: `[(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(x)]` where 3 is my `N` but that clearly doesn't work (outputs `[(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]`).

I can do this with

```
l = []
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        l += [(x,y)]
```

but how can I construct my desired list in a one-liner?

**EDIT** There was clearly a mistake in the list comprehension iteration bounds that confused me. Changing it to `[(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]` would have solved it. Thanks and sorry

Comment: The iteration bounds on your two examples are different. Which of the two do you actually want?

Comment: @NPE that was my mistake. I wanted the latter but used wrong iteration bounds :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do

```
[(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]
```

Comment: Note that *3* is used instead of *x* in the second `range`. This was the problem with the first example in the question description.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.product()`:

```
list(itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you provided (substituting `n` for `3`) can be written in one line as

`[(x, y) for x in range(n) for y in range(n)]`